# Oracle Java Patents Expiration

Tags: patents

Is there a date where the Google v. Oracle situation will never occur again with Java?

It is rather disappointing to me that there is no official date for their patents to expire; see [Java and patents](http://en.swpat.org/wiki/Java). As an example, H.264, which we use for videos [expires in 2027](http://en.swpat.org/wiki/H.264).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_of_patent

Comment: Patents have very definite dates of expiration.

Comment: Google v. Oracle is about copyright, not patents.